# Select and display records from 2 different tables

Tags: php, mysql

I am making a booking system using php and mysql. The system will involve retrieving booking records of different users from mysql. I am currently having difficulties in selecting bookings made by different users. I want to select records based on user logged in.  I have used the code below where it should select records from table bookings as well as the user session. But, this code does not display any bookings.

```
$sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM bookings,users where users.id=  ".$_SESSION['loggedInUser']."";

$results = $mysqli->query($sqlquery);
```

I have been facing this issue for a while and i really want to select bookings made by users login.

Comment: You should use LEFT JOIN between those 2 tables: http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlleftjoin.php

Comment: would you be able to give me an example please and how i could use it

Comment: Does the logged in user have a single booking, or can a user have more than one?

Comment: they can make more than one booking

Comment: A join will only return a single row in most cases, so I'm guessing you are looking to get all the bookings rather than the latest one?

Comment: You need something like: SELECT u.`username`, b.`booking` FROM `users` u LEFT JOIN `bookings` b ON u.`user_id`=b.`user_id` WHERE u.username='.$_SESSION['loggedInUser'].' ... I don't know exactly what are the names of your fields

Comment: yeah all the bookings made by each user

Comment: i have a bookings table which has an id,bookingdate,time   and a users table which has id,username,password, i just need a way of being able to select bookings made by a user

Comment: In you case, where you can have more than one booking per user, I suggest using a pivot table that only has an index, a user_id and a booking_id. This table will store the relation between your user and his bookings.

Comment: yeah all the bookings made by a specific user

Comment: echo $sqlquery; And you need some way of relating users to bookings

Answer (score 0):

You need a pivot table to relate users to bookings:

```
CREATE TABLE user_bookings (id int PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, booking_id int, user_id int);
```

I usually end up using two queries as it allows for better structuring of data. Depending on the size of your website/application, you can use a Object Relation Mapper as it can handle the data mapping internally for you.

If you only need the bookings you can simply select from the pivot table and join bookings like this

```
$bookingsql = "SELECT * FROM user_bookings JOIN bookings on bookings.id =  user_bookings.booking_id where user_bookings.user_id =" . $_SESSION['loggedInUser'];
```

If you need the user details too, you can select the user first and then run the `$bookingsql` query to get the booking details.

```
$usersql = "SELECT * FROM users where id= " . $_SESSION['loggedInUser'];
```

And then, depending on the framework/database driver you're using, transform the `$usersql` query result into an array, called `$user` and assign the bookings to it with the result from `$bookingsql` query.

This can also be achieved with subqueries, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846414/mysql-sql-and-db-for-product-with-multiple-categories) as an example but think of products as your user and categories as your bookings.

Comment: i have tried this way. $sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM bookings,users where users.username= " . $_SESSION['loggedInUser']."";  but i cannot still retrieve any records

Comment: i have tried it and it was not able to display anything

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the query. The idea is that you get your user with `$usersql` and then get the bookings for that user with `$bookingsql`. For that to work, you of course need to store the user ID in `$_SESSION['loggedInUser']`, in case you were storing the username or something else.

Answer (score -1):

To select bookings made by logged user : You should try a `INNER JOIN` :

```
$sqlquery = "SELECT b.* FROM bookings b
 INNER JOIN users u ON u.id_user = b.user_id
 WHERE u.id_user= ".$_SESSION['loggedInUser'];
```

Comment: Your WHERE condition negates your JOIN choice.

Comment: Are you sure about that, or just saying, you can write down some answer first.

Comment: I'm quite sure. `EXPLAIN EXTENDED...` followed by `SHOW WARNINGS;` will prove the point

Comment: I'm still waiting for you to post the correct answer for this topic so we can move on.

Comment: Correct answer to what?

Comment: im still having problems with selecting bookings made by specific users

Comment: @Rohan, do you have a user_id column in your bookings table ?

Comment: I have an id column in both users and bookings table

Comment: when you run this query in your phpAdmin what do you get as a result : `SELECT b.* FROM bookings b
 INNER JOIN users u ON u.id_user = b.user_id
 WHERE u.id_user= #id` => #id is the logged user ID

Comment: does not show any records, the user is logged in with a username which is stored in a session. I just want to display bookings for a specific user that has logged in.

Comment: I have : $username = $_SESSION['loggedin']; $sqlquery = "SELECT b.* FROM bookings b INNER JOIN users u ON u.id = b.id WHERE u.username= '".$_SESSION['loggedin']."'" ;

Comment: is there a way of assigning session to id rather than username since that is most likely the reason to why its not working.

Comment: use `u.id` = $_SESSION['loggedin'] instead of `u.username`